# Есть ли третий такой метод как self и other которые ссылаются на атрибуты класса?

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

Недавно начал изучать ООП в Пайтоне и узнал о таких вещах как `self` и `other` и мне стало интересно, а что если параметров будет больше чем 2, что тогда? Есть ли третий такой метод как `self` и `other`, которые ссылаются на атрибуты класса??

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите какой-нибудь пример. Очень плохо понимаю, что вы спрашиваете

Comment: У вас какая-то полнейшая каша в голове. Ни словом self, ни словом other обычно не называют методы, а «ссылаются на атрибуты класса» без контекста выглядит как ничего не значащий набор случайных слов

Comment: Кстати, в Python нет ключевого слова или оператора `self`. Это просто ооочень распространённое название переменной. По факту первый аргумент метода может именоваться как угодно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любая функция или метод могут принимать любое необходимое количество параметров с любым именем. Метод - это функция, принадлежащая классу. `self` именуют первый параметр метода, который даёт нам способ обращаться к атрибутам этого класса в момент, когда экземпляр класса уже создан. Параметры можете называть как угодно.

Вот пример, здесь конструктор (функция `__init__`) принимает 5 параметров, 4 из которых дополнительные, требующиеся для класса. Так же есть несколько примеров функций. Одна из них - `change_name` служит для смены имени человека (экземпляра класса `Person`), и принимает 3 параметра - `self` и 2 других, которые нужны для логики этой функции `first_name` и `last_name`

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age, born_date):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        # Формат даты рождения dd.mm.yyyy
        self.born_date = born_date

    def get_fullname(self):
        return f'{self.last_name} {self.name}'

    def get_born_year(self):
        # делит строку по точке и возвращает последнюю часть строки, т.е. год из даты
        return self.born_date.split('.')[-1]
    
    def change_name(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.name = first_name
        self.last_name


person = Person('Александр', 'Чёрный', '34', '12.02.1988')
print(person.get_fullname())
print(person.get_born_year())
person.change_name('Василий', 'Дятлов')
print(person.get_fullname())
```

Answer (score 2):

Имена `self` и `other` ни что другое, как конвенция — вы можете применить *какие вам угодны.* (Хотя я вам это не рекомендую, когда хотите, чтобы другие программисты не имели трудности с пониманием вашего кода.)

- **self** значит **я**, в смысле *«я, текущий объект»*.
- **other** значит **другой**, в смысле *«другой операнд (после применения метода к первому)»*.

---

Например

```
def __add__(self, other)
    return self.val + other.val
```

то же самое, как

```
def __add__(x, y)
    return x.val + y.val
```

(В этом примере я предполагаю, что объекты этого класса имеют свойство `val`.)

```
  a   +   b        оператор «+» определен методом:  def __add__(self, other):
  ^       ^                                             return self.val + other.val
self    other
```

---

*Примечание:*

`a + b` *по определению* только сокращенная (инфиксная) запись для `а.__add__(b)`.

В записи `а.__add__(b)` лучше видно, почему имена **self** и **other**:

- `a` принято называть **self** (**я**, ко **мне** применяют метод `.__add__()`)
- `b` принято называть **other** (параметром метода `.__add__()` является **другой** операнд).

Вы можете попробовать это (и с другими операторами-методами):

```
>>> (7).__add__(3)             # то же самое как 7 + 3
10

>>> (7).__mul__(3)             # то же самое как 7 * 3
21

>>> (7).__sub__(3)             # то же самое как 7 - 3
4
```

Целое число `7` должно быть в скобках *только из-за синтаксических причин* —  иначе бы точка прямо за `7` интерпретировалась как десятичное число `7.` (уже не типа `int`, а типа `float`) и нужно бы было поставить *еще одну точку:*

```
>>> 7..__add__(3)              # то же самое как 7.+ 3
10.0
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь до меня дошло

Comment: @Narkoman123, не стоит. :-)